# cant able to copy iframe from one div to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to copy an iframe to another div,its not working
Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            if ($('#d1').html() != $('#d2').html()) {
                $('#d2').html($('#d1').html());
            }
        }, 4000);
    });
</script>
```

And

```
<div id="d1">some stuff<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp" id="iframe1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe closing tag was missing:

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/CQU3G/)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML isnt valid ... the `<iframe>` should be closed using `</iframe>` ... once you fix that it works

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/AmM6u/)

**Note:** doing this kind of copy (ie `$('div1').html($('div2').html()`) causes duplication of `ids` within the document - which is again invalid